# Repeated less-than-equals algorithm

Tags: python, pandas

I know a simple `for`-loopy way to solve this, but I am looking for a better algorithm (mainly to learn. The task requiring this not mission-critical). I have a set of `pandas.Series`, each of variable length, so this must be dynamic. The goal is to take a `Series` from the set, and apply it to a column of a `DataFrame` with a lot of observations. The name of the `Series` is the name of the `DataFrame` column it should be applied to. The application operation is successive less-than-equals, so basically:

1. Sort the Series, in descending order
2. For all values in the corresponding `DataFrame` column less than or equal to the first value in the `Series`, assign the index of the first value in the `Series`
3. Repeat till all values in the Series are exhausted.

Here is a toy example, just applying to one column:

Input:

```
# DataFrame (length is constant)   |   Series (length can change)
      C1    C2    C3    C4   ...   |         Val
ID                                 |  IDX
 0  0.20  0.30  0.10  0.25   ...   |    A0   0.20
 1  0.15  0.04  0.40  0.30   ...   |    A1   0.55
 2  0.65  0.83  0.88  0.61   ...   |    A2   0.90
 3  0.15  0.55  0.45  0.26   ...   |    A3   1.00
 4  0.78  0.83  0.89  0.12   ...   | name: C1 # (Note name matches column name)
 5  0.84  0.75  0.39  0.80   ...   |
 6  0.99  0.83  0.45  0.16   ...   |
 (more than 10^7 observations, and about 15 columns)
```

Output:

```
# DataFrame
    C1    C2    C3    C4   ...
ID
 0  A0  0.30  0.10  0.25   ...
 1  A0  0.04  0.40  0.30   ...
 2  A2  0.83  0.88  0.61   ...
 3  A0  0.55  0.45  0.26   ...
 4  A2  0.83  0.89  0.12   ...
 5  A2  0.75  0.39  0.80   ...
 6  A3  0.83  0.45  0.16   ...
```

Similarly for `C2`, `C3`...

---

My present solution includes a function that does the `greater-than` function application in a loop, and is called using [`pandas.DataFrame.transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.transform.html) function, like so:

```
def less_thn_eq(col, s):
    op = s.copy()
    for i, v in s.sort_values(ascending=False).iteritems():
        op.loc[s <= v] = i

trans_funcs = dict([(s.name, partial(less_thn_eq, s=s)) for s in series_set])
df.transform(trans_funcs)
```

---

Additional notes:

1. Both the `DataFrame` and `Series` are produced by probablistic processes, and therefore all values will always be in the interval `(0, 1)`
2. The `Series` (in case you haven't noticed already) is a cumulative mass function, obtained by `s.cumsum()/s.sum()`
3. The function `less_thn_eq` is actually an inverse mass function, that converts the probablistic observations into real observations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want the numpy digitize function. If there is a typo in your toy example output ('A1' should probably be 'A2'), then the following will be fast.

```
# setup toy example
df = pd.DataFrame( np.array([
 0.20, 0.30, 0.10, 0.25,
 0.15, 0.04, 0.40, 0.30,
 0.65, 0.83, 0.88, 0.61,
 0.15, 0.55, 0.45, 0.26,
 0.78, 0.83, 0.89, 0.12,
 0.84, 0.75, 0.39, 0.80,
 0.99, 0.83, 0.45, 0.16]).reshape(7,4), columns=['C1', 'C2', 'C3', 'C4'])
bins = pd.Series ([0.20, 0.55, 0.90, 1.00], index=['A0', 'A1', 'A2', 'A3'])

# perform digitization
eps = 10**-7
bin_indices = pd.Series(bins.index)
indices = np.digitize(df, bins+eps)
(bin_indices[indices.flatten()]).reshape( df.shape )
Out[94]:
array([['A0', 'A1', 'A0', 'A1'],
       ['A0', 'A0', 'A1', 'A1'],
       ['A2', 'A2', 'A2', 'A2'],
       ['A0', 'A1', 'A1', 'A1'],
       ['A2', 'A2', 'A2', 'A0'],
       ['A2', 'A2', 'A1', 'A2'],
       ['A3', 'A2', 'A1', 'A0']], dtype=object)
```

Comment: Wow! Awesome use of `digitise`. I still don't understand how it works, though. I mean, `eps` is so small, so the bins should be tiny as well. Ps., I fixed the typo in the toy example.

Comment: Also, note that the series only applies to the column with the same name. So in that respect, your answer is slightly wrong. Of course, a simple fix would be to pass just the column to `digitize`, and then it probably won't need the `reshape`...

Comment: :)   eps just ensures the criteria of '<=' is fulfilled. 'digitize' will apply '<' criteria and push equal numbers into the next bin otherwise. You are right about the column name; each column gets its own CDF and in this case flattening and reshaping is not needed.

Answer (score 1):

Setup:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
s = pd.Series([0.20,0.55,0.90,1.00], index = ['A0','A1','A2','A3'], name = 'C1')
df = pd.DataFrame({'C1':[0.20,0.15,0.65,0.15,0.78,0.84,0.99],
                   'C2':[0.30,0.04,0.83,0.55,0.83,0.75,0.83],
                   'C3':[0.10,0.40,0.88,0.45,0.89,0.39,0.45],
                   'C4':[0.25,0.30,0.61,0.26,0.12,0.80,0.16]},
                  )
```

You can get the columns as numpy ndarrays

```
bounds = s.values
test = df[s.name].values
```

Make the comparison by [broadcasting](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/user/basics.broadcasting.html):

```
mask = test[:, None] <= bounds
```

[Find the indices](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.argmax.html#numpy-argmax)

```
new = mask.argmax(axis = 1)
```

Use [array indexing](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/user/basics.indexing.html#index-arrays) with the series' index and assign

```
df[s.name] = s.index[new]


>>> df
   C1    C2    C3    C4
0  A0  0.30  0.10  0.25
1  A0  0.04  0.40  0.30
2  A2  0.83  0.88  0.61
3  A0  0.55  0.45  0.26
4  A2  0.83  0.89  0.12
5  A2  0.75  0.39  0.80
6  A3  0.83  0.45  0.16
>>>
```

---

If you want to perform the operation with the Series on the whole DataFrame

```
bounds = s.values
mask = df.values[..., None] <= bounds
new = mask.argmax(axis = 2)
df[df.columns] = s.index[new]
```

---

This will only work if the Series values are sorted.